# React Native - Packager very slow

Tags: ios, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have a question about speeding up the dev process from react native. If I run `react-native run-ios` in the project root via terminal. A new terminal-window pops out and the packager is running on port 8081. As well as the packager starts also the simulator.

After a few seconds the package says

```
React packager ready.
[5:15:59 PM] <START> request:/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false
[5:15:59 PM] <START> find dependencies
```

After that it takes about 6-10 minutes that the simulator connects to the packager (during this time the simulator throws a few times erros that he can't connect cause he got a timeout). But after the packager is initialized everything works fine. The app has been started and it's connected to the packager.

Everytime when I install new modules (via npm for example) or remove some files I have to delete the app form the simulator and have to run the `react-native run-ios` again. Also sometimes when I changed only code. On the other hand sometimes I can change code and can reload via CMD + R in the simulator and everything works as expected.

Can I speedup the packager or is there something which i missed about reloading? I don't have that many modules installed and the project is at the very beginning (very small)

Comment: Packager takes about 30 seconds for me. I work on Mac.

Comment: Ok. But then your hot loading is working?

Comment: Yes. It works. The packager can be started via npm start.

Comment: Have you installed watchman ?

Comment: Not yet. Is it advisable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native iOS Deployment Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36359330/react-native-ios-deployment-error)